# Jest encountered an unexpected token when testing a Vue single file component

Tags: javascript, vue.js, jestjs

I have a vue application with single file components and i want to add unit tests to test the components.  I'm trying to use jest like described [here](https://vue-test-utils.vuejs.org/guides/testing-single-file-components-with-jest.html) but i keep getting the error "Jest encountered an unexpected token" with the following details:

```
/some_path/MyRecipe.vue:1
<template>
^

SyntaxError: Unexpected token <

  1 | import { shallowMount } from "@vue/test-utils"
> 2 | import MyRecipe from "../src/components/MyRecipe.vue"
    | ^
  3 | 
  4 | describe('MyRecipe', () => {
  5 |   test('is a Vue instance', () => {

  at Runtime._execModule (node_modules/jest-runtime/build/index.js:1166:56)
  at Object.<anonymous> (__tests__/MyRecipe.test.js:2:1)
```

After some research (e.g. from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52637245/jest-with-vuejs-import-es6-fails-syntaxerror-unexpected-token)) I gather that this is probably due to jest expecting a .js file, but the .vue single file components have html, javascript and css in them, usually dealt with by webpack and vue-loader.  I've tried to follow jest configurations from various tutorials to make jest use vue-jest to transform .vue files, but the error persists. This is my package.json file (unnecessary parts removed):

```
{
  "name": "all-recipes ",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    // ...
    "test": "jest"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    // ...
    "core-js": "^3.4.3",
    "vue": "^2.6.10"
    // ...
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@vue/cli-plugin-babel": "^4.1.0",
    "@vue/cli-plugin-eslint": "^4.1.0",
    "@vue/cli-service": "^4.1.0",
    "@vue/test-utils": "^1.0.3",
    "babel-core": "^7.0.0-bridge.0",
    "babel-eslint": "^10.0.3",
    "babel-jest": "^26.0.1",
    // ...
    "jest": "^26.0.1",
    "jest-serializer-vue": "^2.0.2",
    "vue-jest": "^3.0.5",
    "vue-template-compiler": "^2.6.10",
    "vue-test-utils": "^1.0.0-beta.11"
  },
  // ...
  "jest": {
    "moduleFileExtensions": [
      "js",
      "json",
      "vue"
    ],
    "transform": {
      ".*\\.,(vue)$": "vue-jest",
      "^.+\\.js$": "babel-jest"
    },
    "snapshotSerializers": [
      "jest-serializer-vue"
    ]
  }
}
```

Any idea what might be wrong, or some tips on how to debug this?

EDIT: I have looked into [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53415363/jest-vue-syntaxerror-unexpected-token) question and I don't believe the answer there would solve my problem since what I am trying to import is a .vue file and not an .html file.

EDIT 2: I have a feeling that jest is somehow just not picking up the transforms, because removing them from package.json doesn't change anything.

EDIT 3: No, jest is correctly using vue-jest for transforming. If I uninstall vue-jest and try running the test again, jest complains that vue-jest is missing.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Jest + Vue - SyntaxError: Unexpected token <](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53415363/jest-vue-syntaxerror-unexpected-token)

Comment: @JózefPodlecki unfortunately, no.  In the question you reference, the error comes when trying to import an .html file.  I don't believe creating a custom html-loader would solve this problem since the .vue files contain javascript and css as well.

Comment: any reason you have `".*\\.,(vue)$": "<rootDir>/node_modules/vue-jest"` and not just simply [`".*\\.(vue)$": "vue-jest"` as is stated in the docs](https://vue-test-utils.vuejs.org/guides/testing-single-file-components-with-jest.html#processing-single-file-components-in-jest)?

Comment: It was a suggestion from one of the other tutorials I followed, something I tried after initially trying "vue-jest".  I just tried changing it back now, in case something had changed in between now and then, but unfortunately that didn't do the trick.

Comment: To troubleshoot, I would generate a new Vue CLI project, including Jest (which does not have this issue), and figure out the difference from there (e.g., diff it with your project).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The solution to my problem turns out to be a bit anti-climatic.

The problem was that my regexp string to recognize .vue files was wrong and didn't pick up my MyRecipe.vue file. Therefore, vue-jest wasn't used to transform it for jest to interpret, hence the trouble understanding that the file in question started with a very non-js line; `<template>`.  The regexp that works is `^[^.]+.vue$`, so the `transform` section of my package.json file becomes

```
{
  // ...
  "jest": {
    // ...
    "transform": {
      "^[^.]+.vue$": "vue-jest",
      "^.+\\.js$": "babel-jest"
    },
    // ...
  }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Met same issuesome time ago. What i found.

The problem was in the short note of template v-slot

`template(v-slot:body)`

It works to compile, but Jest throws an error

> Jest encountered an unexpected token

```
This usually means that you are trying to import a file which Jest cannot parse, e.g. it's not plain JavaScript.

By default, if Jest sees a Babel config, it will use that to transform your files, ignoring "node_modules".

Here's what you can do:
 • To have some of your "node_modules" files transformed, you can specify a custom "transformIgnorePatterns" in your config.
 • If you need a custom transformation specify a "transform" option in your config.
 • If you simply want to mock your non-JS modules (e.g. binary assets) you can stub them out with the "moduleNameMapper" config option.
```

There was two ways i fount to solve this:

1. Edit my jest.config.js, like this

```
globals: {
  'vue-jest': {
    pug: {
      doctype: 'html',
    },
  },
},
```

2. Write a full note like this
   `template(v-slot:body="")`

Answer (score 2):

What worked for me was changing the transform of the `vue-jest` to what is shown in the documentation.
https://github.com/vuejs/vue-jest

so try using `"^.+\\.vue$": "vue-jest"` instead of `"^[^.]+.vue$": "vue-jest"`
full config might look like this

```
{
  "jest": {
    "moduleFileExtensions": ["js", "json", "vue"],
    "transform": {
      "^.+\\.js$": "babel-jest",
      "^.+\\.vue$": "vue-jest"
     }
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I faced same issues tried many solution but none of them work ..below is following workaround in my case

1. Check package json has following dev dependency entries and jest configurations

   ```
    "devDependencies": {
        "babel-jest": "^23.6.0",
        "@vue/cli-plugin-babel": "~4.5.0",
        "@vue/cli-plugin-eslint": "~4.5.0",
        "@vue/cli-plugin-unit-jest": "~4.5.0",
        "@vue/cli-service": "~4.5.0",
        "@vue/eslint-config-airbnb": "^5.0.2",
        "@vue/test-utils": "^1.0.3",
        "babel-eslint": "^10.1.0",
        "eslint": "^6.7.2",
        "eslint-plugin-import": "^2.20.2",
        "eslint-plugin-vue": "^6.2.2",
          },

     "jest": {
        "moduleFileExtensions": [
        "js",
        "jsx",
        "json",
        "vue"
       ],
     "transform": {
       "^.+\\.vue$": "vue-jest"
       },
    "moduleNameMapper": {
      "^@/(.*)$": "<rootDir>/src/$1"
     },
   "snapshotSerializers": [
      "jest-serializer-vue"
    ],
   "testMatch": [
      "**/tests/unit/**/*.spec.(js|jsx|ts|tsx)|**/__tests__/*. 
   (js|jsx|ts|tsx)"
    ],
    "testURL": "http://localhost/"
    }
   ```

2. Check babel.config.js

   ```
     module.exports = {
       presets: [
       '@vue/cli-plugin-babel/preset',
     ],
    };
   ```
3. check jest.config.js

   ```
     module.exports = {
      preset: '@vue/cli-plugin-unit-jest',
     };
   ```

Answer (score 0):

You need to install **vue-jest** (https://github.com/vuejs/vue-jest) with

```
npm install -D @vue/vue3-jest
```

Here are the available versions and their corresponding vue and jest versions

| Vue version | Jest Version | Package |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Vue 2 | Jest <= 26 | vue-jest@4 |
| Vue 3 | Jest <= 26 | vue-jest@5 |
| Vue 2 | Jest 27 | @vue/vue2-jest |
| Vue 3 | Jest 27 | @vue/vue3-jest |

Then, you'll just have to update your jest configuration (in `jest.config.ts` for example) and add a `transform section`

```js
"transform": {
    "^.+\\.vue$": "@vue/vue3-jest"
}
```

**Warning**: be sure to update the `npm install` and the `jest.config.ts` with the vue-jest package that match your need!